# Making a program operate from system tray in C# .net

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm working on a small internal use utility ATM, and I'd like it to appear in the system tray rather than the task bar. I'd also like it to be minimised there from startup rather than loading the main form. Also I'd like to know how to customise the left click action and right click menu on the system tray icon.

I'm failing to find a detailed walk through on this, so can someone help me to accomplish this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798029.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer of using a NotifyIcon is correct but, like many things .NET, there are a host of subtleties involved in doing it *right*. The tutorial mentioned by Brad gives a good walk-through of the very basics, but does not address any of these:

- Does closing the application from the system tray properly close any open child forms?
- Does the application enforce that only one instance of itself may run (applicable to most, though not all, tray apps) ?
- How to open WPF child windows as well as WinForms child windows, if desired.
- How to support dynamic context menus.
- The standard NotifyIcon exists in WinForms space; can I do a pure WPF solution? (Yes you can!)

I just had an article published on Simple-Talk.com that addresses these points and more in great detail, providing a tray application framework that you can put to use immediately, plus a complete, real-world example application to show everything in practice. See [Creating Tray Applications in .NET: A Practical Guide](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/), published November, 2010.